# Python: how do you store a sparse matrix using python?

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have got an output using sparse matrix in python, i need to store this sparse matrix in my hard disk, how can i do it? if i should create a database then how should i do??
this is my code:

```
import nltk
import cPickle
import numpy
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from nltk.corpus import brown
f = open('spmatrix.pkl','wb')
def markov(L):
    count=0
    c=len(text1)
    for i in range(0,c-2):
        h=L.index(text1[i])
        k=L.index(text1[i+1])
        mat[h,k]=mat[h,k]+1//matrix
    cPickle.dump(mat,f,-1)



text = [w for g in brown.categories() for w in brown.words(categories=g)]
text1=text[1:500]
arr=set(text1)
arr=list(arr)
mat=lil_matrix((len(arr),len(arr)))
markov(arr)
f.close()
```

I need to store this "mat" in a file and should access the value of the matrix using the co-ordinates..

result of the sparse matrix is like this: `the result of sparse matrix are like this:

```
(173, 168) 2.0 (173, 169) 1.0 (173, 172) 1.0 (173, 237) 4.0 (174, 231) 1.0 (175, 141) 1.0 (176, 195) 1.0
```

but when i store it into a file and read the same i'm getting it like this:

```
(0, 68) 1.0 (0, 77) 1.0 (0, 95) 1.0 (0, 100)    1.0 (0, 103)    1.0 (0, 110) 1.0 (0, 112)   2.0 (0, 132)    1.0 (0, 133)    2.0 (0, 139)    1.0 (0, 146)    2.0 (0, 156)    1.0 (0, 157)    1.0 (0, 185)    1.0
```

Comment: Do you have a particular database in mind? What's the size of these matrices? Have you considered sqlite (which Python has built-in support for)?

Comment: i'm a newbie, i don't know much, well i'm just trying to find a solution to store my matrix in harddisk i don't want to run the program to produce the matrix again and again, if i can store the matrix i can just reference the matrix for the values next time.. pls suggest me.. thanks :)

Comment: Please see the following to format your code so it is readable: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, but basically just put 4 spaces before each line of code and then indent as you would otherwise making sure you leave a blank line between code and any normal text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**: This answer is in response to the revise question that now provides code.

You should not call `cPickle.dump()` in your function. Create the sparse matrix and then dump its contents to the file.

Try:

```
def markov(L):
   count=0
   c=len(text1)
   for i in range(0,c-2):
       h=L.index(text1[i])
       k=L.index(text1[i+1])
       mat[h,k]=mat[h,k]+1 #matrix


text = [w for g in brown.categories() for w in brown.words(categories=g)]
text1=text[1:500]
arr=set(text1)
arr=list(arr)
mat=lil_matrix((len(arr),len(arr)))
markov(arr)
f = open('spmatrix.pkl','wb')
cPickle.dump(mat,f,-1)
f.close()
```

Comment: This code runs without errors infact it outputs the matrix to the file leaving a part though!..i'm not able to use this command to.. `mat.dump('output.mat')` where `mat` is my matrix.. This is the error i'm finding `raise AttributeError, attr + " not found"
AttributeError: dump not found`

Comment: You seem to be using some other method now as mat.dump() does not appear in your code or in my suggestion. I apologize, but I do not have the time to help you further. Best of luck.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have a numpy `matrix` or `ndarray`, which your question and tags imply, there is a [`dump`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.dump.html) method and [`load`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) function you can use:

```
your_matrix.dump('output.mat')
another_matrix = numpy.load('output.mat')
```

Comment: so can i use this output.mat anytime i need in other programs??

Comment: Yes. It is just the path to any file on your hard drive where you would like to store the data.

Answer (score 2):

[pyTables](http://www.pytables.org/moin) is the Python interface to HDF5 data model and is pretty popular choice for and well-integrated with NumPy and SciPy.  pyTables will let you access slices of databased arrays without needing to load the entire array back into memory.

I don't have any specific experience with sparse matrices per se and a quick Google search neither confirmed nor denied that sparse matrices are supported.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on the HDF5 support, Python also has [NetCDF support](http://code.google.com/p/netcdf4-python/) which is ideal for matrix form data storage and quick access both sparse and dense. It is included in [Python-x,y](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) for windows, which a lot of scientific users of python end up with.

More numpy based examples can be found in this [cookbook](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/InputOutput).

Answer (score 2):

For very big sparse matrices on clusters, you might use pytrilinos, it has a HDF5 interface which can dump a sparse matrix to disk, and works also if the matrix is distributed on different nodes.

http://trilinos.sandia.gov/packages/pytrilinos/development/EpetraExt.html#input-output-classes

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the size of the sparse matrix, I tend to just use `cPickle` to pickle the array:

```
import cPickle
f = open('spmatrix.pkl','wb')
cPickle.dump(your_matrix,f,-1)
f.close()
```

If I'm dealing with really large datasets then I tend to use `netcdf4-python`

**Edit:**

To then access the file again you would:

```
f = open('spmatrix.pkl','rb') # open the file in read binary mode
# load the data in the .pkl file into a new variable spmat
spmat = cPickle.load(f) 
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) :) if u could explain how to access that spmatrix.pkl it will be of great help.. thanks again :)

Comment: this is the actual input to the file (0, 148) 1.0
  (1, 48) 1.0
  (1, 173) 1.0
  (2, 173) 1.0
  (3, 168) 1.0
  (4, 61) 1.0
  (4, 91) 1.0
  (5, 136) 1.0
  (6, 237) 2.0
  (7, 111) 1.0
but after reading the data from .pkl file i'm getting (0, 148) 1.0
  (0, 48) 1.0
  (0, 173) 1.0
  (0, 173) 1.0
  (0, 168) 1.0
  (0, 61) 1.0
  (0, 91) 1.0
  (0, 136) 1.0
  (0, 237) 2.0
  (0, 111) 1.0
what is the error i have done as u have instructed :(

Comment: I don't understand what your input is. Is it text in a file that you read into python? Please provide the **exact** code you used to generate the pickle. It's probably best if you edit the original question so you can format the code properly.

Comment: Please put the code in your original question using the proper stackoverflow formatting so that I can actually read what you wrote

Comment: **I want to write this matrix "mat" into a file and using the indexes of the matrix i should be able to access the values** using another program!...

Comment: I cannot help you if you do not put the code you wrote above in your **original question** with the proper indentations/formatting

Comment: i'm not able to format the code how can i do it?? when i post it in editor it looks fine after posting the code it appear with out indentation or the color how to format it??

Comment: @JoshAdel it's an old topic but I would be very interested in knowing how you deal with sparse matrix when using netcdf4-python ? I can't find anything on the net and the doc of netcdf4 actually says that netcdf does not deal well with sparse matrix http://www-c4.ucsd.edu/netCDF/netcdf-guide/guide_5.html

Answer (score 2):

For me, using the `-1` option in `cPickle.dump` function caused the pickled file to not be loadable afterwards.

The object I dumped through `cPickle` was an instance of `scipy.sparse.dok_matrix`.

Using only two arguments did the trick for me; [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) about `pickle.dump()` states the default value of the `protocol` parameter is `0`.

Working on Windows 7, Python 2.7.2 (64 bits), and `cPickle` v 1.71.

Example:

```
>>> import cPickle
>>> print cPickle.__version__
1.71
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> H = sparse.dok_matrix((135, 654), dtype='int32')
>>> H[33, 44] = 8
>>> H[123, 321] = -99
>>> print str(H)
  (123, 321)    -99
  (33, 44)  8
>>> fname = 'dok_matrix.pkl'
>>> f = open(fname, mode="wb")
>>> cPickle.dump(H, f)
>>> f.close()
>>> f = open(fname, mode="rb")
>>> M = cPickle.load(f)
>>> f.close()
>>> print str(M)
  (123, 321)    -99
  (33, 44)  8
>>> M == H
True
>>>
```