# How to use HDF to store a very large matrix

Tags: python, matrix, hdf

I am planning to use HDF to store a very large matrix, something like 1e6 x 1e6 of floats.

I would need to read the matrix in batches of consecutive rows or columns.

My question is, **what would be the optimal way to structure/tweak the HDF file to maximize speed?**

Some points:

- I have estimated that reading/writing the full matrix uncompressed in HDF would take ~5 hours on my system. This is reasonable, but it is not reasonable to store the matrix uncompressed, since it will be several terabytes in size.
- If the matrix is sparse, could compression cause reading speed to be comparable or even faster than reading an uncompressed dense matrix?
- Breaking the matrix into separate submatrix datasets would be annoying, since it would complicate reading a row/column from the original matrix or doing things like matrix multiplication. So I would like to avoid this if possible (unless this gives a major speed advantage).
- After reading the matrix once, I plan to read it many times. So read/decompression speed is more important than write/compression speed.
- I am using python h5py to interface with the hdf.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using some sparse representation already, e.g. lil_matrix from scipy.sparse.

I see two plausible options

1) You can dump the binary content to a file using cPickle.dump, see e.g.
[Python: how do you store a sparse matrix using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164106/python-how-do-you-store-a-sparse-matrix-using-python)

2) You can use cPickle to dump the content to a string using cPickle.dumps then afterwards store your content using h5py as a string

In general working with huge amounts of data is costly. When working with e.g. lil_matrix it is the operations on the matrix that is expensive the read/write to disk takes the time it requires to store the data the way there are represented. The overhead of using HDF5 containing a string to a raw C file, is nothing (if you turn off the compression). I would suggest you to turn off the expression, since it doesn't reduce the size much (it is sparse already).